# How to test the equivalence of maps in Golang?

Tags: testing, maps, go, equivalence, table-driven

I have a table-driven test case like this one:

```
func CountWords(s string) map[string]int

func TestCountWords(t *testing.T) {
  var tests = []struct {
    input string
    want map[string]int
  }{
    {"foo", map[string]int{"foo":1}},
    {"foo bar foo", map[string]int{"foo":2,"bar":1}},
  }
  for i, c := range tests {
    got := CountWords(c.input)
    // TODO test whether c.want == got
  }
}
```

I could check whether the lengths are the same and write a loop that checks if every key-value pair is the same. But then I have to write this check again when I want to use it for another type of map (say `map[string]string`).

What I ended up doing is, I converted the maps to strings and compared the strings:

```
func checkAsStrings(a,b interface{}) bool {
  return fmt.Sprintf("%v", a) != fmt.Sprintf("%v", b) 
}

//...
if checkAsStrings(got, c.want) {
  t.Errorf("Case #%v: Wanted: %v, got: %v", i, c.want, got)
}
```

This assumes that the string representations of equivalent maps are the same, which seems to be true in this case (if the keys are the same then they hash to the same value, so their orders will be the same). Is there a better way to do this? What is the idiomatic way to compare two maps in table-driven tests?

Comment: Err, no: The order iterating a map is not guaranteed to be [predictable](http://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements): _"The iteration order over maps is not specified and is not guaranteed to be the same from one iteration to the next. ..."_.

Comment: Furthermore for maps of certain sizes Go will intentionally randomize the order. It's highly advisable not to depend on that order.

Comment: Trying to compare a map is a design flaw in your program.

Comment: Note that with go 1.12 (Feb. 2019), **Maps are now printed in key-sorted order to ease testing**. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54173309/6309)

Answer (score 261, accepted):

The Go library has already got you covered. Do this:

```
import "reflect"
// m1 and m2 are the maps we want to compare
eq := reflect.DeepEqual(m1, m2)
if eq {
    fmt.Println("They're equal.")
} else {
    fmt.Println("They're unequal.")
}
```

If you look at the [source code](http://golang.org/src/pkg/reflect/deepequal.go?s=2432:2441#L98) for [`reflect.DeepEqual`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#DeepEqual)'s `Map` case, you'll see that it first checks if both maps are nil, then it checks if they have the same length before finally checking to see if they have the same set of (key, value) pairs.

Because `reflect.DeepEqual` takes an interface type, it will work on any valid map (`map[string]bool, map[struct{}]interface{}`, etc). Note that it will also work on non-map values, so be careful that what you're passing to it are really two maps. If you pass it two integers, it will happily tell you whether they are equal.

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I was looking for. I guess as jnml was saying it's not as performant, but who cares in a test case.

Comment: Yeah, if you ever want this for a production application, I'd definitely go with a custom-written function if possible, but this definitely does the trick if performance isn't a concern.

Comment: @andras You should also check out [gocheck](http://labix.org/gocheck). As simple as `c.Assert(m1, DeepEquals, m2)`. What's nice about this is it aborts the test and tells you what you got and what you expected in the output.

Comment: It's worth noting that DeepEqual also [requires the ORDER of slices to be equal](https://play.golang.org/p/70fYlqhRWL).

Comment: [Documentation for DeepEqual](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#DeepEqual).

Comment: @Xeoncross thank you for the link, but it is better to add it to the answer.

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich I did add it to the answer, it's just 270px lower than you wanted.

Comment: @Xeoncross I think it is better to always try to minimize the amount of comments - because they collapse after 10, and inserting inside the answer provides better context. For example this comment (my comment) is not an answer, so it is real comment.

Comment: if map type is map[int64][]int64 then deep equals fails.
Example: https://play.golang.org/p/2skYYgnAfl9
        m1 := make(map[int64][]int64, 0)
 m2 := make(map[int64][]int64, 0)

 m1[1] = []int64{1, 2}
 m2[1] = []int64{2, 1}
 fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual(m1, m2)) // prints false

Comment: @efex09 Slices are only considered equal if they have the same elements in the same order. So `{1, 2}` and `{2, 1}` are not considered equal: https://play.golang.org/p/YWHqvROUtpY

Answer (score 26):

> What is the idiomatic way to compare two maps in table-driven tests?

You have the project [`go-test/deep`](https://github.com/go-test/deep) to help.

But: this should be easier with **Go 1.12** (February 2019) *natively*: See [release notes](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.12#fmt).

```
fmt.Sprint(map1) == fmt.Sprint(map2)
```

> ### `fmt`

> **Maps are now printed in key-sorted order to ease testing**.
>
> The ordering rules are:
>
> - When applicable, nil compares low
> - ints, floats, and strings order by `<`
> - NaN compares less than non-NaN floats
> - `bool` compares `false` before `true`
> - Complex compares real, then imaginary
> - Pointers compare by machine address
> - Channel values compare by machine address
> - Structs compare each field in turn
> - Arrays compare each element in turn
> - Interface values compare first by `reflect.Type` describing the concrete type and then by concrete value as described in the previous rules.
>
> When printing maps, non-reflexive key values like NaN were previously displayed as `<nil>`. As of this release, the correct values are printed.

Sources:

- [`golang/go` issue 21095](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/21095),
- [Tweet](https://twitter.com/mikesample/status/1084223662167711744) (original idea for that patch: [ᴊᴀᴍᴇꜱ ᴊᴜꜱᴛ ᴊᴀᴍᴇꜱ (`purpleidea`)](https://twitter.com/purpleidea)
- [CL 142737](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/142737/):

The CL adds: ([CL stands for "Change List"](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/build/cmd/cl))

> To do this, we add [a package at the root, `internal/fmtsort`](https://github.com/golang/go/tree/7cbfa55b5d17c8deaecff05e4221f828467cfa97/src/internal/fmtsort), that implements a general mechanism for sorting map keys regardless of their type.
>
> This is a little messy and probably slow, but formatted printing of maps has never been fast and is already always reflection-driven.
>
> The new package is internal because we really do not want everyone using this to sort things. It is slow, not general, and only suitable for the subset of types that can be map keys.

Also use the package in `text/template`, which already had a weaker version of this mechanism.

You can see that used in [`src/fmt/print.go#printValue(): case reflect.Map:`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/7cbfa55b5d17c8deaecff05e4221f828467cfa97/src/fmt/print.go#L748-L759)

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, I'm new to Go, but how exactly does this new `fmt` behavior help to test the equivalence of maps? Are you suggesting to compare the string representations instead of using `DeepEqual`?

Comment: @sschuberth `DeepEqual` is still good. (or [rather `cmp.Equal`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45222521/6309)) The use case is more illustrated in https://twitter.com/mikesample/status/1084223662167711744, like diffing *logs* as stated in the original issue: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/21095. Meaning: depending on the nature of your test, a reliable diff can help.

Comment: `fmt.Sprint(map1) == fmt.Sprint(map2)` for the tl;dr

Comment: @425nesp Thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 16):

This is what I would do (untested code):

```
func eq(a, b map[string]int) bool {
        if len(a) != len(b) {
                return false
        }

        for k, v := range a {
                if w, ok := b[k]; !ok || v != w {
                        return false
                }
        }

        return true
}
```

Comment: OK, but I have an other test case where I want to compare instances of  `map[string]float64`. `eq` only works for `map[string]int` maps. Should I implement a version of the `eq` function every time I want to compare instances of a new type of map?

Comment: @andras: 11 SLOCs. I'd "copy paste" specialize it in shorter time than it takes to ask about this. Though, many others would use "reflect" to do the same, but that's of much worse performance.

Comment: doesn't that expect the maps to be in the same order? Which go does not guarantee see "Iteration order" on https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action

Comment: @nathj07 No, because we iterate only through `a`.

Comment: As of go1.18+, you may  make it generic. e.g https://go.dev/play/p/0RtJT32O5wU

Answer (score 13):

Use cmp (https://github.com/google/go-cmp) instead:

```
if !cmp.Equal(src, expectedSearchSource) {
    t.Errorf("Wrong object received, got=%s", cmp.Diff(expectedSearchSource, src))
}
```

[image: Failed test]

It does still fail when the map "order" in your expected output is not what your function returns. However, `cmp` is still able to point out where the inconsistency is.

For reference, I have found this tweet:

https://twitter.com/francesc/status/885630175668346880?lang=en

> "using reflect.DeepEqual in tests is often a bad idea, that's why we open sourced http://github.com/google/go-cmp"
>   - Joe Tsai

Answer (score 6):

**Disclaimer**: Unrelated to `map[string]int` but related to testing the equivalence of maps in Go, which is the title of the question

If you have a map of a pointer type (like `map[*string]int`), then you [do **not** want to use reflect.DeepEqual](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/golang-nuts/reflect.deepequal$20map%7Csort:relevance/golang-nuts/UWKAOXyMwJM/97sLfGmHgiQJ) because it will return false.

Finally, if the key is a type that contains an unexported pointer, like time.Time, then reflect.DeepEqual on such a map [can also return false](https://play.golang.org/p/iuVUfT6ZNT).

Answer (score 5):

Use the "Diff" method of [github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp](https://godoc.org/github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp#Diff):

Code:

```
// Let got be the hypothetical value obtained from some logic under test
// and want be the expected golden data.
got, want := MakeGatewayInfo()

if diff := cmp.Diff(want, got); diff != "" {
    t.Errorf("MakeGatewayInfo() mismatch (-want +got):\n%s", diff)
}
```

Output:

```
MakeGatewayInfo() mismatch (-want +got):
  cmp_test.Gateway{
    SSID:      "CoffeeShopWiFi",
-   IPAddress: s"192.168.0.2",
+   IPAddress: s"192.168.0.1",
    NetMask:   net.IPMask{0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00},
    Clients: []cmp_test.Client{
        ... // 2 identical elements
        {Hostname: "macchiato", IPAddress: s"192.168.0.153", LastSeen: s"2009-11-10 23:39:43 +0000 UTC"},
        {Hostname: "espresso", IPAddress: s"192.168.0.121"},
        {
            Hostname:  "latte",
-           IPAddress: s"192.168.0.221",
+           IPAddress: s"192.168.0.219",
            LastSeen:  s"2009-11-10 23:00:23 +0000 UTC",
        },
+       {
+           Hostname:  "americano",
+           IPAddress: s"192.168.0.188",
+           LastSeen:  s"2009-11-10 23:03:05 +0000 UTC",
+       },
    },
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way:

```
    assert.InDeltaMapValues(t, got, want, 0.0, "Word count wrong. Got %v, want %v", got, want)
```

Example:

```
import (
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "testing"
)

func TestCountWords(t *testing.T) {
    got := CountWords("hola hola que tal")

    want := map[string]int{
        "hola": 2,
        "que": 1,
        "tal": 1,
    }

    assert.InDeltaMapValues(t, got, want, 0.0, "Word count wrong. Got %v, want %v", got, want)
}
```