# How to check for an empty struct?

Tags: struct, go

I define a struct ...

```
type Session struct {
    playerId string
    beehive string
    timestamp time.Time
}
```

Sometimes I assign an empty session to it (because nil is not possible)

```
session = Session{};
```

Then I want to check, if it is empty:

```
if session == Session{} {
     // do stuff...
}
```

Obviously this is not working. How do I write it?

Comment: Session{} isn't an "empty" session; it's initialized with each field being the zero value.

Comment: I am curious, why don't you use an interface instead? If I were to write a session handler, I would not expect a session with empty fields. Could lead to more problem than its worth.

Comment: Maybe you want to formulate this as an answer. I cannot recall why I did this in this project in 2015 ;-)

Answer (score 326, accepted):

You can use == to compare with a zero value composite literal because all fields in `Session` are [comparable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators):

```
if (Session{}) == session  {
    fmt.Println("is zero value")
}
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/wRUmxj1naS)

Because of a [parsing ambiguity](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals), parentheses are required around the composite literal in the if condition.

The use of `==` above applies to structs where all fields are [comparable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators). If the struct contains a non-comparable field (slice, map or function), then the fields must be compared one by one to their zero values.

An alternative to comparing the entire value is to compare a field that must be set to a non-zero value in a valid session. For example, if the player id must be != "" in a valid session, use

```
if session.playerId == "" {
    fmt.Println("is zero value")
}
```

Comment: So I get an error, `struct containing []byte cannot be compared`, because, well, my struct contains a byte slice.

Comment: @Nevermore The answer applies to a struct with comparable fields. If your struct contains non-comparable values like []byte, then you need to write code to test all fields or use the reflect package as outlined in another answer.

Comment: As mentioned by @Nevermore, `==` comparison with slice fields will fail. For comparing these structs, use either `reflect.DeepEqual` or consider something more specialized like discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534072/how-to-compare-struct-slice-map-are-equal

Comment: "parsing ambiguity in [if condition]" saved my day, thanks :) coz when I was trying it in fmt.Println(session == Session{}), it works.

Comment: In performance-sensitive scenarios, is checking a struct value faster than empty struct comparison? e.g `session.timestamp == nil` vs `(Session{}) == session`

Answer (score 66):

Here are 3 more suggestions or techniques:

#### With an Additional Field

You can add an additional field to tell if the struct has been populated or it is empty. I intentionally named it `ready` and not `empty` because the zero value of a `bool` is `false`, so if you create a new struct like `Session{}` its `ready` field will be automatically `false` and it will tell you the truth: that the struct is not-yet ready (it's empty).

```
type Session struct {
    ready bool

    playerId string
    beehive string
    timestamp time.Time
}
```

When you initialize the struct, you have to set `ready` to `true`. Your `isEmpty()` method isn't needed anymore (although you can create one if you want to) because you can just test the `ready` field itself.

```
var s Session

if !s.ready {
    // do stuff (populate s)
}
```

Significance of this one additional `bool` field increases as the struct grows bigger or if it contains fields which are not comparable (e.g. slice, `map` and function values).

#### Using the Zero Value of an Existing Field

This is similar to the previous suggestion, but it uses the zero value of an existing field which is considered *invalid* when the struct is not empty. Usability of this is implementation dependant.

For example if in your example your `playerId` cannot be the empty `string` `""`, you can use it to test if your struct is empty like this:

```
var s Session

if s.playerId == "" {
    // do stuff (populate s, give proper value to playerId)
}
```

In this case it's worth incorporating this check into an `isEmpty()` method because this check is implementation dependant:

```
func (s Session) isEmpty() bool {
    return s.playerId == ""
}
```

And using it:

```
if s.isEmpty() {
    // do stuff (populate s, give proper value to playerId)
}
```

#### Use Pointer to your struct

The second suggestion is to use a Pointer to your struct: `*Session`. Pointers can have `nil` values, so you can test for it:

```
var s *Session

if s == nil {
    s = new(Session)
    // do stuff (populate s)
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Thank you, icza!

Comment: Awesome answer! I think following the last choice looks pretty idiomatic.

Answer (score 38):

Just a quick addition, because I tackled the same issue today:

With Go 1.13 it is possible to use the new `isZero()` method:

```golang
if reflect.ValueOf(session).IsZero() {
     // do stuff...
}
```

I didn't test this regarding performance, but I guess that this should be faster, than comparing via `reflect.DeepEqual()`.

Answer (score 30):

Using [reflect.deepEqual](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#DeepEqual) also [works](http://play.golang.org/p/UsMuDZlnli), especially when you have map inside the struct

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"
import "reflect"

type Session struct {
    playerId string
    beehive string
    timestamp time.Time
}

func (s Session) IsEmpty() bool {
  return reflect.DeepEqual(s,Session{})
}

func main() {
  x := Session{}
  if x.IsEmpty() {
    fmt.Print("is empty")
  } 
}
```

Comment: using reflect.DeepEqual is a very clean solution but i wonder if it takes more  processing time? i assume it is comparing every field, plus you introduce a new import.

Answer (score 8):

Keep in mind that with pointers to struct you'd have to dereference the variable and not compare it with a pointer to empty struct:

```
session := &Session{}
if (Session{}) == *session {
    fmt.Println("session is empty")
}
```

Check this [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/i4EjqJvALc).

Also here you can see that a struct holding a property which is a slice of pointers cannot be compared the same way...

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the other answers, it's possible to do this with a syntax similar to the way you originally intended if you do it via a `case` statement rather than an `if`:

```
session := Session{}
switch {
case Session{} == session:
    fmt.Println("zero")
default:
    fmt.Println("not zero")
}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/kgIqmRnA2M)

Answer (score 1):

@cerise-limón's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28447372/8367711) was the best. Though, if you get `struct containing ... cannot be compared` error like below.

```golang
type Friends struct {
    nice []string
    mute []string
}

type Session struct {
    playerId  string
    beehive   string
    timestamp time.Time
    friends   Friends
}

func main() {
    session := Session{}
    if (Session{}) == session  {
        fmt.Println("zero")
    }
}

// Output: ./prog.go:23:17: invalid operation: Session{} == session (struct containing Friends cannot be compared)
```

The above, `Friends`' object is causing an error.

The **easy way** to fix it is to define as a pointer in the field.

```golang
type Friends struct {
    nice []string
    mute []string
    
}

type Session struct {
    playerId  string
    beehive   string
    timestamp time.Time
    friends   *Friends // <--- here
}

func main() {
    session := Session{}
    if (Session{}) == session  {
        fmt.Println("zero")
    }
}

// Output: zero
```

- [Go Playground Example](https://play.golang.org/p/ElRYDoKH7MS)

Answer (score 0):

Using `fmt.Sprintf` can help to detect is a `struct` empty or not. When it is empty the output is `{ }`.

This suggestion is useful for working with JSONs and where the `struct` doesn't have a specific name.

```
if fmt.Sprintf("%v", session) == "{ }" {
    // session is empty
}
```