# How to check empty struct which only contains one boolean field

Tags: go

```
type Test struct { }
```

I knew this may be the way to check empty struct by `(Test{}) == test`. However, it seems not working for the struct which only contains one boolean field. Considering this example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Test struct {
  Foo bool
}

func main() {
  empty := Test{}
  test1 := Test{Foo: true}
  test2 := Test{Foo: false}
  fmt.Println(Test{} == test1) //False yay
  fmt.Println(Test{} == test2) //True oh no ...
  fmt.Println(Test{} == empty) //True yay
}
```

Basically, == thinks the struct containing `false` field is same to empty struct.

Is there a better way to check **the empty struct** or am I missing something here ?

Also, you may wonder why only have one field in struct, well, because the struct is in development phase, it may have more fields later on.

Comment: `empty` contains one field, you just didn't explicitly set it to anything.

Comment: *"Basically, == thinks the struct containing `false` field is same to empty struct. "* This is because in Go they are the same. If you need to differentiate between **zero values** and **"uninitialized" values** then you'll have to work around this language feature by adding one more bit of information to the value/field. E.g. by making it a pointer or by using a `struct` type like the `sql.NullXxx` types found in `database/sql`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check for an empty struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28447297/how-to-check-for-an-empty-struct)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Struct types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types)
>
> A struct is a sequence of named elements, called fields, each of which
>   has a name and a type. Field names may be specified explicitly
>
> ```
> // An empty struct.
> struct {}
> ```
>
> [Composite literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals)
>
> Composite literals construct values for structs, arrays, slices, and
>   maps and create a new value each time they are evaluated. They consist
>   of the type of the literal followed by a brace-bound list of elements.
>   Each element may optionally be preceded by a corresponding key.
>
> A literal may omit the element list; such a literal evaluates to the
>   zero value for its type.
>
> [The zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value)
>
> When storage is allocated for a variable, either through a declaration
>   or a call of new, or when a new value is created, either through a
>   composite literal or a call of make, and no explicit initialization is
>   provided, the variable or value is given a default value. Each element
>   of such a variable or value is set to the zero value for its type:
>   false for booleans, 0 for numeric types, "" for strings, and nil for
>   pointers, functions, interfaces, slices, channels, and maps. This
>   initialization is done recursively, so for instance each element of an
>   array of structs will have its fields zeroed if no value is specified.

---

```
type Test struct {
  Foo bool
}

empty := Test{}
```

`empty` is not empty. It is the zero value.

```
zeroValue := Test{}
```

or, explicitly,

```
zeroValue := Test{Foo: false}
```

Comment: empty not empty. It is the zero value. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

The struct `Test` always contains the boolean field `Foo`. It is just initialized to `false` if you don't specify its value.

Comment: understood, but how do I check the empty struct in this case ?

Comment: There is no empty struct. `Test` is defined to have a `Foo` field.