# How to check for &{<nil> } in golang

Tags: go

I am trying to check whether the struct is nil or not from the db query but its not working.
`fmt.Println(loginResponse) //` `&{<nil>   }`

```
if !reflect.ValueOf(loginResponse).IsNil() { // Its not working

        response := models.Response{
            Message: "Login Success",
            Success: true,
            Output:  token,
        }
        return c.JSON(response)

    } 


if !reflect.ValueOf(loginResponse).IsZero() { // its also not working

        response := models.Response{
            Message: "Login Success",
            Success: true,
            Output:  token,
        }
        return c.JSON(response)

    }
```

Both the conditions are not working .Please help

Login response

```
type LoginResponse struct {
    Id          interface{} `json:"_id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Email       string      `json:"email"`
    Gender      string      `json:"gender"`
    PhoneNumber string      `json:"phonenumber"`
}
```

Comment: Show what `loginResponse` is?

Comment: If what you pass is a pointer to a struct which contains a nil pointer (`&something{nil}`), it's not the same as passing a nil pointer (`nil`).

Comment: Yeah but how to check it then ?

Comment: Are you checking for zero value of struct? See [How to check for an empty struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28447297/5291015)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this ,hopefully it works

```
if (LoginResponse{}) != *loginResponse { // as your getting address so derferencing the pointer to struct

        response := models.Response{
            Message: "Login Success",
            Success: true,
            Output:  token,
        }
        return c.JSON(response)

    }
```