# Avoiding Go copying interface data

Tags: go, reference, pass-by-reference

This is part of real world code I'm trying to write. The problem is that Go copies the interface `sibling` so I can't modify the data. However, if I change to using a pointer to an interface then the concept of equality fails. I know I can use `DeapEquals`, but not in a map.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Q interface {
    modify()
}

type P struct {
    name    string
    sibling Q
}

func (x P) modify() {
    x.name = "a"
}

func main() {
    a := P{"a", nil}
    A := P{"?", nil}

    b := P{"b", a}
    B := P{"b", A}

    B.sibling.modify()

    fmt.Println(B)
    fmt.Println(b == B)
}
```

How do I get Go to let me modify the interface data itself without copying it and modifying the copy?

It seems these are mutually exclusive on a struct:

- I need to be able to use maps
- I need to be able to modify the interface data with methods

Answer (score 3):

The only way to modify the data without copying it is to use pointers.

I'm a little confused by what you are saying as your example uses a struct and you talk about structs but then you say you need to be able to use maps. Either way, DeepReflect works with both. [Here](https://play.golang.org/p/MFu4m8rSaj) is your example modified to use pointers:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Q interface {
    modify()
}

type P struct {
    name    string
    sibling Q
}

func (x *P) modify() {
    x.name = "a"
}

func main() {
    a := P{"a", nil}
    A := P{"?", nil}

    b := P{"b", &a}
    B := P{"b", &A}

    B.sibling.modify()

    fmt.Println("a:", a)
    fmt.Println("A:", A)
    fmt.Println("b:", b)
    fmt.Println("B:", B)
    fmt.Println(b == B)
    fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual(b, B))
}
```

Prints:

```
a: {a <nil>}
A: {a <nil>}
b: {b 0x10436180}
B: {b 0x10436190}
false
true
```

And you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534072/golang-how-to-compare-struct-slice-map-is-equal) post for doing the same with maps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use value returned from modify()

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Q interface {
    modify() Q           //See here
}

type P struct {
    name    string
    sibling Q
}

func (x P) modify() Q{    //Here
    x.name = "a"
    return x
}

func main() {
    a := P{"a", nil}
    A := P{"?", nil}

    b := P{"b", a}
    B := P{"b", A}

    B.sibling=B.sibling.modify() //And here

    fmt.Println(B)
    fmt.Println(b == B)
}
```

It's verbose a bit, but at least works https://play.golang.org/p/8oM90wriN0