# How to check if parameter passed into function is nil in Go?

Tags: go

Need to check if parameter being passed to func is nil and return 0.

Below is my intended code

```
func (t *Transaction) GetOperationCount(input bean.Request) (int, error) {
    var result int = 0
    if input == nil { //error here
        return result, nil
    }
    // Other code here!!!!
    return result, nil
}
```

`bean.Reques` is a struct. 
However it had issue: "cannot convert nil to type bean.Request input Request". I have trying

```
if (bean.Request{})== input
```

But it gives :

```
"json:\"MV_STATUS\""; NDFNFFP string "json:\"NDF_NFFP\""; NDFNFMV string "json:\"NDF_NFMV\"" } "json:\"attr\"" } "json:\"marke
t_value\"" } "json:\"market_values\"" } "json:\"tick\"" } "json:\"insertion\"" } "json:\"operation\"" } "json:\"transaction\"" 
} cannot be compared)
```

Should I change the parameter to "input *bean.Request" ?

Comment: The problem here is the problem description itself: "check if parameter being passed to func is nil". The only things which *can* be nil are pointers, interfaces, and slices/maps/channels. If `bean.Request` is none of them the question itself is not well formed. Reformulate the question to be explicit which condition on `bean.Request` you want to check; beeing nil is impossible,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, here is the working version:

```
func (t *Transaction) GetOperationCount(input *bean.Request) (int, error) {
    var result int = 0
    if input == nil {
        return result, nil
    }
    // Other code here
    return result, nil
}
```

---

You have some options (depending to your use case, see: [Pointers vs. values in parameters and return values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542989/pointers-vs-values-in-parameters-and-return-values)):

1- You may use pointer (`input *bean.Request`) and compare it with `nil`
2- you may use another struct and compare it with `reflect.DeepEqual(r, zero)`
3- You may write your own `compare` function (or method with pointer or value receiver)

See this sample (try it on [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/HYi6DlLedZ)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func (t *Transaction) GetOperationCount(input *Request) (int, error) {
    var result int = 0
    if input == nil {
        return result, nil
    }
    // Other code here
    return result, nil
}

func main() {
    var input *Request
    if input == nil {
        fmt.Println("input is nil.") //input is nil.
    }

    input = &Request{}
    if input != nil {
        fmt.Println("input is not nil.") //input is not nil.
    }
    r := Request{}
    fmt.Printf("Zero value: %#v\n", r) //Zero value: main.Request{I:0}

    zero := Request{}
    fmt.Println("r == zero :", r == zero) //r == zero : true

    fmt.Println("DeepEqual :", reflect.DeepEqual(r, zero)) //DeepEqual : true
    fmt.Println("compare   :", compare(&r, &zero))         //compare   : true

}
func compare(r, zero *Request) bool {
    return r.I == zero.I
}

type Request struct {
    I int
}
type Transaction struct{}
```

output:

```
input is nil.
input is not nil.
Zero value: main.Request{I:0}
r == zero : true
DeepEqual : true
compare   : true
```

---

[Comparison operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators):

4- You may compare it with its zero value (nil for pointers, and if it is `struct` it's zero value is Empty struct if it is like `struct{}` (not `nil`), or struct with all fields initialized to their zero values):

[The zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value):

> When storage is allocated for a variable, either through a declaration
>   or a call of new, or when a new value is created, either through a
>   composite literal or a call of make, and no explicit initialization is
>   provided, the variable or value is given a default value. Each element
>   of such a variable or value is set to the zero value for its type:
>   false for booleans, 0 for integers, 0.0 for floats, "" for strings,
>   and nil for pointers, functions, interfaces, slices, channels, and
>   maps. This initialization is done recursively, so for instance each
>   element of an array of structs will have its fields zeroed if no value
>   is specified.
>   These two simple declarations are equivalent:
>
> ```
> var i int
> var i int = 0
> ```
>
> After
>
> ```
> type T struct { i int; f float64; next *T }
> t := new(T)
> ```
>
> the following holds:
>
> ```
> t.i == 0
> t.f == 0.0
> t.next == nil
> ```
>
> The same would also be true after
>
> ```
> var t T
> ```

---

See "reflect.DeepEqual": [How to compare struct, slice, map are equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534072/how-to-compare-struct-slice-map-are-equal)

```
func DeepEqual(x, y interface{}) bool
```

Docs:

> ```
>  DeepEqual reports whether x and y are ``deeply equal,'' defined as follows.
>  Two values of identical type are deeply equal if one of the following cases applies.
>  Values of distinct types are never deeply equal.
>
>  Array values are deeply equal when their corresponding elements are deeply equal.
>
>  Struct values are deeply equal if their corresponding fields,
>  both exported and unexported, are deeply equal.
>
>  Func values are deeply equal if both are nil; otherwise they are not deeply equal.
>
>  Interface values are deeply equal if they hold deeply equal concrete values.
>
>  Map values are deeply equal if they are the same map object
>  or if they have the same length and their corresponding keys
>  (matched using Go equality) map to deeply equal values.
>
>  Pointer values are deeply equal if they are equal using Go's == operator
>  or if they point to deeply equal values.
>
>  Slice values are deeply equal when all of the following are true:
>  they are both nil or both non-nil, they have the same length,
>  and either they point to the same initial entry of the same underlying array
>  (that is, &x[0] == &y[0]) or their corresponding elements (up to length) are deeply equal.
>  Note that a non-nil empty slice and a nil slice (for example, []byte{} and []byte(nil))
>  are not deeply equal.
>
>  Other values - numbers, bools, strings, and channels - are deeply equal
>  if they are equal using Go's == operator.
>
>  In general DeepEqual is a recursive relaxation of Go's == operator.
>  However, this idea is impossible to implement without some inconsistency.
>  Specifically, it is possible for a value to be unequal to itself,
>  either because it is of func type (uncomparable in general)
>  or because it is a floating-point NaN value (not equal to itself in floating-point comparison),
>  or because it is an array, struct, or interface containing
>  such a value.
>  On the other hand, pointer values are always equal to themselves,
>  even if they point at or contain such problematic values,
>  because they compare equal using Go's == operator, and that
>  is a sufficient condition to be deeply equal, regardless of content.
>  DeepEqual has been defined so that the same short-cut applies
>  to slices and maps: if x and y are the same slice or the same map,
>  they are deeply equal regardless of content.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Yes..The error itself mentions that it cannot compare both. You can use pointer to compare with nil or create an empty struct to compare.