# Check if struct is empty if struct contains json.RawMessage

Tags: go, struct, equality

I'm trying to create a method extension to check if my struct was initialized but I'm getting this error:

> invalid operation: myStruct literal == inStruct (struct containing json.RawMessage cannot be compared)

Here's my code:

```
package datamodels

import "encoding/json"

type myStruct struct {
        a string json:"a"
        b json.RawMessage json:"b"
        c json.RawMessage json:"c"
    }

func (m *myStruct ) IsEmpty() bool {
    return (myStruct {}) == m 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that `json.RawMessage` is a Alias for a `[]byte` and maps, slices etc can not be compared normally.

You can compare slices with `reflect.DeepEqual` method.

See example below.

```
package main

import "encoding/json"
import "reflect"

type myStruct struct 
{
        a string `json:"a"`
        b json.RawMessage `json:"b"`
        c json.RawMessage `json:"c"`
}   

func (m myStruct ) IsEmpty() bool {
    return reflect.DeepEqual(myStruct{}, m)
}


func main() {
    var mystuff myStruct = myStruct{}

    mystuff.IsEmpty()
}
```

[GOLANG Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/gi2gEccdow)

Reference for comparing slices: [How to compare struct, slice, map are equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534072/how-to-compare-struct-slice-map-are-equal)

See the `RawMessage` type.
json.RawMessage type: https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/stream.go?s=6218:6240#L237

Comment: This does the trick. Clean and simple. Thanks for providing the actual code, the GOLANG Playground link and reference.

Answer (score 1):

The zero value of `myStruct` is a struct where `a`, `b` and `c` are zero values of their type. The zero value of a string is `""`, of `json.RawMessage` it is `nil` (because it's just an alias for `[]byte`). Combining this knowledge you get:

```
type myStruct struct {
    a string
    b json.RawMessage
    c json.RawMessage
}

func (m *myStruct ) IsEmpty() bool {
    return m.a == "" && m.b == nil && m.c == nil
}
```

There is no need for `reflect.DeepEqual()`

Comment: this does the job but I prefer not specifying every single field/property of my struct. There has to be a better way since my struct actually have twenty fields/properties.