# Go structs comparison - reflect.DeepEqual fails on maps?

Tags: go

I'm writing unit test and my goal is to unmarshall data from json to one struct and compare it to the other, mock struct. I'm using reflect.DeepEqual() method but it's returning false on these.

My guess is that it is somehow related to type casting going on in the background, where map[string]interface{} is converted to map[string]int, but that's as far as I got.

```
type MyStruct struct {
    Cache map[string]interface{} `json:"cache"`
}

var js = `{"cache":{"productsCount":28}}`

func main() {
    var s1, s2 MyStruct
    s1 = MyStruct{
        Cache: map[string]interface{} {
            "productsCount": 28,
        },
    }
    s2 = MyStruct{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(js), &s2)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", s1)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", s2)
    fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual(s1, s2))
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
main.MyStruct{Cache:map[string]interface {}{"productsCount":28}}
main.MyStruct{Cache:map[string]interface {}{"productsCount":28}}
false
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare struct, slice, map are equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534072/how-to-compare-struct-slice-map-are-equal)

Comment: I don't see it as duplicate, that thread is much more general

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The thing here is how the golang encoding an `int`, you're initializing it as `int`, but in the json you provide it is `float64`.

Here is working example:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "reflect"
)

type MyStruct struct {
    Cache map[string]interface{} `json:"cache"`
}

var js = `{"cache":{"productsCount":28}}`

func main() {
    var s1, s2 MyStruct
    s1 = MyStruct{
        Cache: map[string]interface{}{
            "productsCount": float64(28),
        },
    }
    s2 = MyStruct{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(js), &s2)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", s1)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", s2)
    fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual(s1, s2))
}
```

Output:

```
main.MyStruct{Cache:map[string]interface {}{"productsCount":28}}
main.MyStruct{Cache:map[string]interface {}{"productsCount":28}}
true
```

Comment: thanks, this is excactly the explanation I needed. I was missing knowledge about json marshalling details.